# Can I know where I need to go to experience a given weather type?

Tags: online-resources, weather-and-climate

Of course I can simply consult the weather pages for a set of possible places. This can be quite tedious though. What I want to do is to be able to locate where to go in say a 100 km range where I would have a less then 20% chance of rain.

Can I consult some online resource that would answer such questions?

I am currently using a weather source like [buienradar](http://www.buienradar.nl/) to get a rather accurate indication where it is raining and where it isn't. I would appreciate to have a similar resource that would visualise (see example of buienradar below) weather predictions in the near future.

[image]

Comment: For any particular period of time or just averages?

Comment: For a specific day. (ie. tomorrow or the day after tomorrow)

Comment: In my experience, weather forecasts are generally not accurate enough to be able to predict significant differences in weather over distances as short as 100km.

Comment: @nateEldredge In my experience they can be. It mainly depends on the landscape. In a lot of areas you sometimes simply need to drive 20km to get a total opposite weather type.

Comment: @NateEldredge For a day ahead they can be, certainly if there are mountains in-between.  For a week ahead, likely not.

Comment: It depends on where you're talking about. In some places, weather prediction is far easier than in others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about weather forecasting, not travel :/

Comment: @markmayo it is about doing a hiking trip with friends where good weather is required.

Comment: @Andra I know, and I realise the attempt, but ... I don't know. Maybe a reword. I don't think we can reliably answer, given that weather reports aren't reliable :/

Answer (score 6):

You want to consult a proper weather map.  I like [Wetter3](http://wetter3.de/) and [Wzkarten](http://www.wzkarten.de/).

For Wetter3, click on [Standardkarten](http://wetter3.de/animation.html), then in the drop-down menu on "Niederschlagsumme".  Then, with the arrows next to "Termin", scroll to the relevant time (indicated in UTC).  You can change the area with "Gebiet" — note that the alternate GEFS output is listed as a separate option here.  For 24 hours ahead, you might get a map like this:

[image: Europe precip forecast +30 hours]

or, for cloudiness a bit later (select Gesamtbewoelkung):

[image: Europe cloudiness forecast +30 hours]

or, from another model, the probability of getting at least 1 mm of precipitation within 6 hours (select Europe (GEFS) in Gebiet, then "Wahrsch. fuer Niederschl (>1.0)"):

[image: Europe, precip probability forecast GEFS, +30 hours]

if you're in The Netherlands, bad luck... nowhere to go for your criteria (unless you have a boat)!

You can also select other areas and indicators, such as temperature.  The interface is in German and it shows the direct output from the GFS weather model, so many indicators are relatively expert and it may be less accurate than data processed by an experienced meteorologist.  But the simpler outputs such as temperature and precipitation give a good indication of where to go for good weather within the next week or so.

WZkarten has a similar functionality, and additionally offers "spaghetti plots" that plot several models within the same map.  This gives an indication of uncertainty — but for the next 48 hours or so, that normally shouldn't be a major issue.

Answer (score 4):

For the US, you can use the [National Weather Service](http://graphical.weather.gov/).  Zoom in on the area of interest, select the desired time period with the "+/-12Hrs" buttons, and mouse over "12 hr. probability" next to "Probability of Precip." to get a color-coded map showing the predicted chance of rain.  You can mouse over other entries of the table to see predictions for temperature, humidity, wind, cloud cover, etc.